# Access Ubuntu Server from other network via Filezilla?

Tags: networking, ftp, remote-access, routing, filezilla

Just want to apologize in advance if this is a obvious question, or I leave anything out. I have tried searching for the answer on my own but couldn't find what I was looking for so came here

So basically, the other day I made an Ubuntu server to host a website.
I am using FileZilla to SSH into my server and edit files to develop my site.
I'm working on this project with a mate who lives in a different area, and I was wondering if I could set it up so that he could access my server via FileZilla?

Thanks in advance, Bryn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your server is in your home on your home network, and not a VPS (Virtual Private Server, something you'd rent monthly), you need to forward port 22 (the SSH port) and port 80 (the HTTP port) in your router to your server.

The address you use to access the server (such as 192.168.1.101, for example) will not work since they are not in your local network. You will need to provide your friend with your public/WAN IP address, which can be found by going to a site such as http://ipecho.net/ on any computer on your network. Assuming you correctly forward the ports needed, going to this public IP will work for them like your current method does for you. You can also use this IP yourself to test it.

Note: Your public IP is liable to change, unless your ISP has given you a static IP. Power outages, modem/router reboots, or expiration of the assignment can cause this to change, and you'll have to find out the new one and give it to your friend again.

Here is a nice walkthrough on the basics of assigning a static IP to your server, and additional information on choosing IPs and why:
https://www.howtogeek.com/184310/ask-htg-should-i-be-setting-static-ip-addresses-on-my-router/

Then you need to forward the ports. The specific methods for each router and network setup vary a little, so use this as a guideline. Ignore the section in this article on setting static IPs, as that was written for windows, and it's generally better to do that in your router, to avoid conflicts:
https://www.pcworld.com/article/244314/how_to_forward_ports_on_your_router.html

**Update:** This was the solution to the problem, but some personal help navigating the router port forwarding part was necessary.

Comment: I host it myself although it is hosted inside virtualbox... Not sure if this makes any difference. I have tried to give him this IP and both of the mentioned ports are already forwarded. When I try to connect it says it timed out after 20 seconds. If you could add me on discord and try to help me out that would be brilliant! Bryn#3077

Comment: I'm about to head home, but I'll add you and message you in about 20 minutes. Sounds like you need to configure Virtualbox's networking. The default mode is NAT, which won't allow connections back to the box from outside your machine. The easiest solution is probably to switch it to bridged mode. I can help with that, or maybe this link will help:
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-set-bridged-networking-in-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine/

Comment: Thanks very much, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Little late, but I am here!